# unstable decryption, sometimes got cipher: message authentication failed

Tags: go, encryption

I'm trying to create E2E Encryption for my software, but the decryption are very unstable, sometime can successfully decrypt, sometime got `cipher: message authentication failed`, here's my encrypt & decrypt code

```
func Encrypt(data []byte, passphrase string) ([]byte, error) {
    // create aes.NewCipher from hashed md5 passphrase
    block, _ := aes.NewCipher([]byte(createHash(passphrase)))
    //  NewGCM returns the given 128-bit, block cipher wrapped in
    // Galois Counter Mode with the standard nonce length.
    gcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(block)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // initialize slice with length of nonce that must be passed to Seal and Open.
    nonce := make([]byte, gcm.NonceSize())
    if _, err = io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, nonce); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    ciphertext := gcm.Seal(nonce, nonce, data, nil)
    return ciphertext, nil
}

func Decrypt(data []byte, passphrase string) ([]byte, error) {
    // create md5 byte slice
    key := []byte(createHash(passphrase))
    // just `reverse` algorithm with passphrase until return
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    gcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(block)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    nonceSize := gcm.NonceSize()
    nonce, ciphertext := data[:nonceSize], data[nonceSize:]
    plaintext, err := gcm.Open(nil, nonce, ciphertext, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return plaintext, nil
}
```

the encrypted binary value are transferred via http :

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

decrypt, err := Decrypt(body, r.Passphrase)
```

what i already try is to check, is `ioutil.ReadAll` read content correctly, or something wrong with decryptor

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in this code. Add the implementation for createHash, so we can rule that out as the source for the errors. Assuming createHash is correct that leaves incorrect passphrases (especially since you say it works some of the time but not always; always a sign of incorrect keys). Double check that they are what you think they are. That being said, MD5 is a *terrible* choice for deriving encryption keys. Use a cryptographically strong derivation function instead, such as PBKDF2, argon2, bcrypt, scrypt, etc. Also consider using TLS instead of rolling your own crypto.

Comment: @Peter it's MD5, i used it because has single-result hash, i'll try crypto, but this one is much simpler

Comment: there must be something wrong with `ioutil.ReadAll` on response body, here the full code http://github.com/codenoid/gotral

Comment: Obviously you shouldn't prefer simplicity over security in cryptography. MD5 (or any other fast hash for that matter) is bad because someone observing the ciphertext can do the exact same thing as someone getting their hands on a database containing MD5 hashes of passwords: try a few billion per second to find the encryption key for very little money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, the problem was not in encryption/decryption, but in http server for transferring the chipertext, and already fixes now https://github.com/codenoid/GoTral-Server/commit/493c7f654753cae36f074c1c5f382953e227d295